# jq: combine multi array in dict without permutate

Tags: jq

> are there have any way to achieve simply as expected?
>
> it using combine with permutate in default.

The Following Case

**source**

```json
{
    "title":["title1","title2"],
    "link":["http://testapi.cn","http://testapi.org"]
}
```

**expression** `[{title:.title[],link:.link[]}]`

**console**

```json
[
  {
    "title": "title1",
    "link": "http://testapi.cn"
  },
  {
    "title": "title1",
    "link": "http://testapi.org"
  },
  {
    "title": "title2",
    "link": "http://testapi.cn"
  },
  {
    "title": "title2",
    "link": "http://testapi.org"
  }
]
```

**expected**

```json
[
  {
    "title": "title1",
    "link": "http://testapi.cn"
  },
  {
    "title": "title2",
    "link": "http://testapi.org"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transpose` to generate an array of arrays with one element of each input array.

```
[.title,.link] | transpose | map({title:.[0],link:.[1]})
```